# Редирект со страницы с параметрами

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Есть страница `http://new.mydomain.ru/catalog/category/?set_filter=y&arbFilter_230_1525441506=Y`. Необходимо поставить редирект с нее на страницу `http://mydomain.ru/catalog/category/subcategory`.

В `.htaccess`'е пишу:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^set_filter=y&arbFilter_230_1525441506=Y$
RewriteRule ^catalog/category/$ http://mydomain.ru/catalog/category/subcategory [R=301,L]
```

Но должного эффекта не наблюдается. Что я не так делаю?

Comment: Вроде всё норм. Единственное, если вам не нужны аргументы (`?set_filter=y&arbFilter_230_1525441506=Y`), то поставьте знак вопроса в конец: `RewriteRule ^catalog/category/$ http://mydomain.ru/catalog/category/subcategory? [R=301,L]` Т.е. на выходе получится `http://mydomain.ru/catalog/category/subcategory` без аргументов. Проверить [можно здесь](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

Comment: Со знаком "?" тоже происходит непонятное. То есть параметры из урла не убираются при редиректе. А получается следующее: `http://mydomain.ru/catalog/category/?set_filter=y&arbFilter_230_1525441506=Y`

Comment: Возможно проблема в регистрозависимости аргументов. У вас заглавные и строчных буквы чередуются. Можно использовать флаг `[NC]`. Т.е. `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^set_filter=y&arbFilter_230_1525441506=Y$ [NC]`

Comment: pkrymskaya, комментарии ограничены в форматировании. Используйте для этого редактирование своего вопроса.

Comment: @romeo Пожалуйста, оформите ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, у Вас в `.htaccess`'е выше этого правила стоит еще редирект на саму категорию.

Т.е. что-то вроде:

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/category/$ http://mydomain.ru/catalog/category/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Да, так и было. Спасибо!